# creating a new promise with async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

So I have a bunch of promises I'm trying to batch complete like so:

```
let promises = [];
let fixedValues = [];
let shouldIQuit = false;
let value = {
    b: 1
};

promises.push(
   new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const shouldquit = await shouldIQuit(shouldIQuitValue);

      if(shouldquit === true) {
          const fixedValue = await Values.fixThisValue(value);

          if(!fixedValue.a) {
            resolve();
           }

         fixedValues.push(fixedValue);
      }

    resolve();
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

the other functions can do anything, but I need both to be awaited. It should first call the `shouldIquit` function, check that value, then await the result of `fixThisValue` and then determine if that number should be put into the array or not, and I need to do this all in parallel.

However, I'm noticing that sometimes when `fixedValue` comes back without `fixedValue.a` and it successfully hits that `resolve();` in the if, it still makes it down to push the fixed value into the array `fixedValues` when it shouldn't. I'm thinking it's the `async` in the promise creating a problem. Any help with that is much appreciated.

Comment: does `if(!fixedValue.a) {
            resolve();
           }
         fixedValues.push(fixedValue);` need to be `if(!fixedValue.a) {
            resolve();
           }
         else {
         fixedValues.push(fixedValue);}`

Comment: `resolve` is not equivalent to `return`.  There is no flow control associated with resolving a promise. Execution continues to the next statement after you call the `resolve()` function.  If you want you can `return resolve();` to exit your function after resolving the promise since you don't seem to be using the return value anyway.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 3):

> when fixedValue comes back without fixedValue.a and it successfully hits that resolve(); in the if, it still makes it down to push the fixed value into the array fixedValues when it shouldn't

I think you're hoping that `resolve()` works as a return statement (exiting the function).

```
         const fixedValue = await Values.fixThisValue(value);

          if(!fixedValue.a) {
            resolve();
           }

         fixedValues.push(fixedValue);
```

`resolve()` doesn't exit the function. You could update your code to do an early return

```
if(!fixedValue.a) {
  resolve();
  return;
}
            
fixedValues.push(fixedValue);
```

or you could add an `else` block

```
if(!fixedValue.a) {
  resolve();
} else {
  fixedValues.push(fixedValue);
}
```

Comment: beat me to it!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return resolve()` otherwise the code will keep running past the 'if'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a return after `resolve` or otherwise rearrange the flow of your code.

```js
promises.push(
   new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const shouldquit = await shouldIQuit(shouldIQuitValue);

      if ( shouldquit ) {
         const fixedValue = await Values.fixThisValue(value);
         if ( fixedValue.a ) {
            fixedValues.push( fixedValue );
         }
      }

      resolve();
   }
);
```

Alternate take:

```js
promises.push(
   new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const shouldquit = await shouldIQuit(shouldIQuitValue);

      if ( shouldquit ) {
         const fixedValue = await Values.fixThisValue(value);
         if ( fixedValue.a ) {
            resolve( fixedValue );
         }
      }

      resolve( undefined );
   }
);

let fixedValues = ( await Promise.all(promises) ).filter( _ => _ !== undefined  );
```